# How to create form controllers dynamically in angular 2+ using Reactive forms

Tags: typescript, angular8

I have an array with questions.I have to read it and show questions dynamically.So I have few questions related to it.

1) I have no idea how to initialize controllers to FormBuilder instance.

2) how to create questions dynamically

3) how to add validations dynamically

I created this project using angular 8.

Mainly I have 4 types of questions in a survey.

1. MCQ ( only have to select one answer)
2. Multiple Select ( User can select multiple answers)
3. Ranking question ( user have to give the correct order of answers)
4. Descriptive ( Users own answer can give)

Here is my array with questions

```
questions: any = [
{
  id: 11,
  surveyNo: 5,
  qNo: 1,
  question: 'What is the country you would like to travel?',
  qType: 1,
  noAnswrs: 4,
  answerType: 1,
  answrs: ['America', 'Australia', 'India', 'England']
},
{
  id: 12,
  surveyNo: 5,
  qNo: 2,
  question: 'What type of credit cards do you have?',
  qType: 2,
  noAnswrs: 4,
  answerType: 1,
  answrs: ['Visa', 'Mastercard', 'American Express', 'Discover']
},
{
  id: 13,
  surveyNo: 5,
  qNo: 3,
  question: 'Please rank the following features in order of importance,where 1 is the most important to you.?',
  qType: 3,
  noAnswrs: 4,
  answerType: 1,
  answrs: ['Location', 'Confort', 'Service', 'Value for money']
},
{
  id: 14,
  surveyNo: 5,
  qNo: 4,
  question: 'What is your idea about our institute?',
  qType: 4,
  noAnswrs: 0,
  answerType: 1,
  answrs: []
}];
```

here is html code

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header  bg-transparent border-success">
                    <h3>15 questions</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <form [formGroup]="surveyQuestionForm">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label"> 1) What is the country you would like to
                                        travel?</label>
                                    <div class="ml-3">
                                        <table>
                                            <th width="auto"></th>
                                            <th width="auto"></th>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>1. America</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class=" custom-radio custom-control">
                                                        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="q1_1"
                                                            name="q1" value="1" formControlName="q1" />
                                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="q1_1">

                                                        </label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>2. Australia </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class=" custom-radio custom-control">
                                                        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="q1_2"
                                                            name="q1" value="2" formControlName="q1" />
                                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="q1_2"></label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>3. India </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="custom-radio custom-control">
                                                        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="q1_3"
                                                            name="q1" value="3" formControlName="q1" />
                                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="q1_3"></label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>4. England </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class=" custom-control  custom-radio">
                                                        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="q1_4"
                                                            name="q1" value="4" formControlName="q1" />
                                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="q1_4"></label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>





                                    </div>
                                </div>
                               
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label"> 2) What type of credit cards do you have?</label>
                                    <div class="ml-3">
                                        <table>
                                            <th width="auto"></th>
                                            <th width="auto"></th>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>1. Visa </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="q2_1"
                                                            value="1" formControlName="q2" />
                                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="q2_1"></label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>2. Mastercard</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="q2_2"
                                                            value="2" formControlName="q2" />
                                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="q2_2"></label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>3. American Express</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="q2_3"
                                                            value="3" formControlName="q2" />
                                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="q2_3"></label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>4. Discover</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="q2_4"
                                                            value="4" formControlName="q2" />
                                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="q2_4"></label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label"> 3) Please rank the following features in order of importance,where 1 is the most important to you.?</label>
                                    <div class="ml-3">
                                        <table>
                                             
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>1. Location </td>
                                                <div class="invalid-feedback"
                                                 *ngIf="surveyQuestionForm.get('q3').touched && surveyQuestionForm.get('q3').hasError('required')">Answer required</div>
                                                 <div class="invalid-feedback"
                                                 *ngIf="surveyQuestionForm.get('q3').touched && surveyQuestionForm.get('q3').hasError('max')">max value</div>
               
                                                <td><input type="number" style="width:40px;" id="q3_1"  
                                                    [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': surveyQuestionForm.get('q3').errors && surveyQuestionForm.get('q3').touched}"
                                                        formControlName="q3" class="text-center" /></td>
                                            </tr>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td>2. Confort </td>
                                                <td><input type="number" style="width:40px;" id="q3_1"  
                                                         class="text-center" /></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>3. Service </td>
                                                <td><input type="number" style="width:40px;" id="q3_1"  
                                                          class="text-center" /></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>4. Value for money </td>
                                                <td><input type="number" style="width:40px;" id="q3_1"  
                                                          class="text-center" /></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>


                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label"> 4) What is your idea about our institute?</label>
                                    <div class="ml-3">
                                        <table>
                                            <th width="auto"></th>
                                            <th></th>

                                            <tr>

                                                <td><textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="text"
                                                        formControlName="q4"></textarea></td>
                                            </tr>

                                        </table>


                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is typescript code

```
 surveyQuestionForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
  questions: any = [
    {
      id: 11,
      surveyNo: 5,
      qNo: 1,
      question: 'What is the country you would like to travel?',
      qType: 1,
      noAnswrs: 4,
      answerType: 1,
      answrs: ['America', 'Australia', 'India', 'England']
    },
    {
      id: 12,
      surveyNo: 5,
      qNo: 2,
      question: 'What type of credit cards do you have?',
      qType: 2,
      noAnswrs: 4,
      answerType: 1,
      answrs: ['Visa', 'Mastercard', 'American Express', 'Discover']
    },
    {
      id: 13,
      surveyNo: 5,
      qNo: 3,
      question: 'Please rank the following features in order of importance,where 1 is the most important to you.?',
      qType: 3,
      noAnswrs: 4,
      answerType: 1,
      answrs: ['Location', 'Confort', 'Service', 'Value for money']
    },
    {
      id: 14,
      surveyNo: 5,
      qNo: 4,
      question: 'What is your idea about our institute?',
      qType: 4,
      noAnswrs: 0,
      answerType: 1,
      answrs: []
    }
  ];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForms();
  }
  createForms(): any {
    this.surveyQuestionForm = this.fb.group({
      q1: ['', [Validators.required]],
      q2: ['', [Validators.required]],
      q3: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(1), Validators.max(3)]],
      q4: ['', [Validators.required]]
     });
  }
```

Here is the  questions preview
 [image]

Here are the validators have to use

1. required validator
2. min value(1) and max value(4)
3. have to check already inserted value inserted or not (no idea how to do this dynamically)

I red many articles,but those are not in dynamically create.
Please help me to do this

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not very clear what you're after, but it would look something like this I think....

```
private buildSubGroup(question) {
  switch (question.qType) {
    case 2:
      return this.fb.group(
        question.answers.reduce((subGroup, answer) => {
          return Object.assign(subGroup, {[answer]: [false]});
        }, {}), {validators: [atLeastOneRequired()]} // validation rules here unclear? is at least 1 required?
      );
    case 3:
      return this.fb.group(
        question.answers.reduce((subGroup, answer) => {
          return Object.assign(subGroup, {[answer]: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(1), Validators.max(3)]]});
        }, {}), {validators: [uniqueNumbersValidator()]}
      );
    case 1: // it's counter intuitive but these are actually the same structure due to how angular handles radio input
    case 4:
      return this.fb.group({answer: ['', [Validators.required]]});
    default:
      throw new Error('unhandled question type');
  }
}

this.surveyQuestionForm = this.fb.group(
  this.questions.reduce((group, question) => {
    return Object.assign(group, {['q' + question.qNo]: this.buildSubGroup(question)});
  }, {});
);
```

so basically, you take your questions array and reduce them to an object with 'q' plus the qNo as keys and the values are the sub form group which depends on the qType... you also need some group level custom validators that needs to be written to confirm that each number only appears once and at least one is selected, which could look like this:

```
   function atLeastOneRequired() {
     return (ctrl: AbstractControl) => {
       let fg = ctrl as FormGroup;
       let atLeastOneTrue = Object.values(fg.controls).some(fc => !!fc.value);
       return (atLeastOneTrue ) ? null : {atLeastOneRequired: true};
     };
   }

   function uniqueNumbersValidator() {
     return (ctrl: AbstractControl) => {
       let fg = ctrl as FormGroup;
       let allUnique = true;
       let values = [];
       Object.values(fg.controls).forEach(fc => {
         let val = fc.value;
         if (val && allUnique) {
           if (values.includes(val)) {
             allUnique = false;
             break;
           }
           values.push(val);
         }
       });
       return (allUnique) ? null : {notAllUnique: true};
     }
   }
```

the template binding itself would be fairly different from how you have it, but this answers how to build the form control in a dynamic fashion.  You could build the question templates by iterating over the questions array and binding appropriately with formGroupName and formControlName directives and the ngSwitch directive in a similar manner as I used switch statements here to build the form groups.

Comment: thanks alot for your reply,
actually I have 4 types of questions.This question is 2nd type one.So in template I want to read questions array and check the question type(qType) and generate the question.
In this question I have to check qType === 2 then generate this question.Can you please help me to do this?
And uniqueNumbersValidator() have to add only this type question.If you want I can give you an array with all the 4 type questions.

Comment: I’d need to see the full array of types to write a full answer but what’s here should give you an idea of what writing dynamic forms looks like

Comment: I updated question and added all the things.Please help me

Comment: i showed how to build the form groups for all the question types.  past that is a new question.

Comment: Thanks alot brayan,Can you please give me an idea about how to do this in template also?

Comment: the scope of this question is building form controls dynamically. dynamic templating is a different topic.

Comment: In the top of question added few questions I had
in that question list 2nd one is
2) how to create questions dynamically 

In this line I meant by the template generate part.anyway thanks for your help.I'll try this

Comment: bryan60, can you please explain what happen from this code?
return this.fb.group(
          question.answers.reduce((subGroup, answer) => {
            return Object.assign(subGroup, { [ answer ]: [false] });
          }, {}), { validators: [this.atLeastOneRequired()] }
        );
I meant can you show me this like
this.fb.group({
      firstname: ['', Validators.required] });

Comment: It’s building a form group for the check boxes. Creates an object that looks like {Visa:[false], Discover: [false]} with all the card types. Then puts a validation on the group that requires at least one option be selected. Don’t know if that part was required but it doesn’t make any sense to say every checkbox is required.

Comment: bryan60,I have some questions in html template, So is it ok to add new question or can you please answer it under this question?

Comment: If the code here has answered your questions regarding building dynamic form controls and validators, then you should mark it as accepted. And attempt the templating on your own with the hints I’ve given. If you get stuck, ask another question with the code you’ve tried and link it here

Comment: according to your answer  type 3 question answer is always checked,I  don't want to check any value by default.
I'll defensively mark this question  after resolve this issue.And I created another question,please if you can help me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57127588/how-to-generate-dynamically-reactive-forms-in-angular-8

Comment: type 3 doesnt have any checks? not sure what you mean.

Comment: sorry,not type 3,its type 2, it only displaying checkboxes and 1 checkbox show as checked one.I added complete code in my second question

Comment: I’ll take a look but this code definitely doesn’t default anything to checked for type 2. Have a stack blitz or something?

Comment: checked your blitz, it was an issue in how you were binding, not how the form was being built.