# ng-template with *ngFor issue in angular 8

Tags: typescript, primeng, angular8

I want to create a table with dynamically generated columns.
I used [PrimeNg](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup) library for the grid.

I opened many questions,but no one replied me,please help me to do this.

I used  with *ngFor to generate table column headers

There are 2 arays. one for the row data and one for columns names.

Here is my row data array.which contains one row

```
uersSurveyAnswers: any = [
    {
      userEmail: 'amara@gmail.com',
      qustns: [
        {
          qNo: 1,
          ansrs: ['1']
        },
        {
          qNo: 2,
          ansrs: ['1', '0', '1', '1']
        },
        {
          qNo: 5,
          ansrs: ['2']
        },
        {
          qNo: 6,
          ansrs: ['0', '1', '1', '0']
        }
      ]
    }];
```

Columns to data should be load below wise

```
column Q1.1 - > uersSurveyAnswers -> qustns[0].ansrs[0]
column Q2.1 - > uersSurveyAnswers -> qustns[1].ansrs[0]
column Q2.2 - > uersSurveyAnswers -> qustns[1].ansrs[1]
column Q2.3 - > uersSurveyAnswers -> qustns[1].ansrs[2]
column Q2.4 - > uersSurveyAnswers -> qustns[1].ansrs[3]
column Q5.1 - > uersSurveyAnswers -> qustns[2].ansrs[0]
column Q6.1 - > uersSurveyAnswers -> qustns[3].ansrs[0]
column Q6.2 - > uersSurveyAnswers -> qustns[3].ansrs[1]
column Q6.3 - > uersSurveyAnswers -> qustns[3].ansrs[2]
column Q6.4 - > uersSurveyAnswers -> qustns[3].ansrs[3]
```

Here is my html code

```
<p-table [columns]="columns" [value]="uersSurveyAnswers">
                            <ng-template pTemplate="header"  let-columns>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        Respondent Name
                                    </th>
                                    <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                                        {{col.header}}
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </ng-template>
                            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-surveyAnswer let-columns="columns">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{surveyAnswer.userEmail}}</td>
                                     <td>{{surveyAnswer.qustns[0].ansrs[0]}}</td>
                                    <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                                             {{col.field}}
                                        </td>
                                </tr>
                            </ng-template>
                        </p-table>
```

Here is my columns array

```
columns = [
{
field: 'qustns[0].ansrs[0]',
header: 'Q1.1'
},
{
field: 'qustns[1].ansrs[0]',
header: 'Q2.1'
},
{
field: 'qustns[1].ansrs[1]',
header: 'Q2.2'
},
{
field: 'qustns[1].ansrs[2]',
header: 'Q2.3'
}
,
{
field: 'qustns[1].ansrs[3]',
header: 'Q2.4'
}
,
{
field: 'qustns[2].ansrs[0]',
header: 'Q5.1'
}
,
{
field: 'qustns[3].ansrs[0]',
header: 'Q6.1'
}
,
{
field: 'qustns[3].ansrs[1]',
header: 'Q6.2'
}
,
{
field: 'qustns[3].ansrs[2]',
header: 'Q6.3'
}
,
{
field: 'qustns[3].ansrs[3]',
header: 'Q6.4'
}]
```

this array is generated by dynamically.

Now my problem is,
inside my second '**ng-template**' tag contains **let-surveyAnswer** which contains the row data.

If I create column with

```
<td>{{surveyAnswer.qustns[0].ansrs[0]}}</td>
```

Then it's showing the row data

but I can't understand how to do this in html like below

```
<td *ngFor="let col of columns">
  {{col.field}}
</td>
```

**col.field** contains columns array data like

```
qustns[0].ansrs[0]
```

I want to get the data like below

```
<td *ngFor="let col of columns">
      {{surveyAnswer.col.field}}
    </td>
```

Here is Stackblitz url https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ggvf31

Please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `ngOnInit()` method. You are trying to set the field values like this:

```js
{
  field: 'qustns[0].ansrs[0]',
  header: 'Q1.1',
}
```

But that means you are setting `field` to the string `'qustns[0].ansrs[0]'`, when you actually want the value. Change them to be like:

```js
{
  field: this.uersSurveyAnswers[0].qustns[0].ansrs[0],
  header: 'Q1.1',
}
```

Comment: Collierre, thanks alot for your reply,
I updated my stackblits app. Can you please check it.
But it's not showing data.
I can't do this,if it's working,then it's only loading first row data.Foor this question I only added one index array,but that array contains many indexes.so how I do this method for all the rows

Comment: Have a look in the console on stackblitz. It says `Error: this.uersSurveyAnswers[0].ustns is undefined`. You need to change `ustns` to `qustns` in the second last object of `this.columns`.

Comment: If you want to make it work with many rows, are all the user answers the same? I.e. does question 1 always have one answer, question 2 always has 4 answers etc.?