# How to create button dynamically with click event in angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I want to create a button dynamically.I used innerHtml to do this.
I can create button.But it's click event not working.
Please tell me how to solve this?

Here is my html code

```
<div  [innerHTML]="answerPanelContent"></div>
```

Here is my typescript code

```
 answerPanelContent: any;

   constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){

   }
ngOnInit() {
 this.answerPanelContent =  this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`<button type="button" class="btn                                                    btn-primary float-left"
                                           (click)="removeAnswer()" title="Remove Answer"
                                           aria-label="Close">
                                          Remove</button>`);

  }
    removeAnswer(){
      alert('clicked');
    }
```

Here is the stackblitz url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nka4w9

Comment: It is because it will not be angular controlled component, just plaint non sanitized html.

Comment: If I assign it as a non sanitized,then button not displaying

Comment: The proper way to do it is to put the HTML **in the template**, not in the TypeScript code. Use `*ngIf="buttonShown"` on the button in the template, and in the TS code set `this.buttonShown` to true to make it appear.

Comment: @JB Nizet, I can't do that,I created this question for only know how to do this dynamically.Actually what I want is, I have a input field with a button.If I entered something and after clicks that button,I have to show that input value with a button.That button clicks after that field have to close.
Here is the full question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57345041/how-to-dynamically-create-table-rows-with-buttons-by-button-click-in-angular-2

Comment: That doesn't change anything. Put the HTML code in the template, and use ngIf to remove or add it to the page based on the state of the component. Or ngFor to generate one row per element of an array of data.

Comment: Case is,
Here is the steps I have to do.
I have a input field with a button.If I input value after clicks that buttons,then my inner html part to show that input field with a button.That button has a click event.So sometimes there are few input values I have to enter and click.so after that it will create many buttons.So how to do it as your way?Please help me,I can't understand this clearly

Comment: @JB Nizet, are you know any method to run *ngFor loop by button click?

Comment: Your description is quite unclear to me. You don't "run an ngFor loop by button click". You add an element to an array, and the ngFor that displays all the elements of the array automatically detects the change and displays the new element. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h4mj8y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts for a basic example.

Comment: @SupunAravinda, Would you please try my answer and let me know if it works... Within a second of posting the answer, somebody downvoted it. If it doesn't work for you, I will delete my answer

Comment: @JB Nizet, Actually it's working,I'm confusing,from the beginning I tried this way,but it's not worked.I meant it's not detected newly added values.thanks a lot  ah :)

Comment: JB Nizet, and  Adrita Sharma, both of your answers working for me.So which one I have to select as the correct one :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I strongly recommend **not** using `[innerHTML]` for this. It is not meant for this purpose and not the "angular way" at all.

### Using *ngFor

This is the most preferable way to solve your issue and "the angular way".

**component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  public buttonsTexts:Array<string> = ['First button'];

  public addButton(index:number):void {
    this.buttonsTexts = [...this.buttonsTexts, `button ${index}`];
  }
}
```

**template.html**

```
<button 
   *ngFor="let buttonText of buttonsTexts; let i = index;"
   (click)="addButton(i)">{{buttonText}}</button>
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s5cdmq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

### Using Renderer2

Use this **only** if `*ngFor` is not able to solve your issue because of some requirements that we don't know.

**component.ts**:

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
 
  @ViewChild('inserttarget', {static: false})
  public insertTarget:ElementRef; // use this if you want to insert inside a specific element in your template

  constructor(
    private renderer:Renderer2, 
    private el:ElementRef // use this if you want to insert into your template's root
  ) {

  }

  public ngAfterViewInit():void {
    this.addNewButton();
  }


  public addNewButton():void {
    const button = this.renderer.createElement('button');
    const buttonText = this.renderer.createText('Click me');

    this.renderer.appendChild(button, buttonText);
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.insertTarget.nativeElement, button); // use this.el.nativeElement to insert into template root
    this.renderer.listen(button, 'click', () => this.addNewButton());
  }
}
```

**template.ts**

```
<p #inserttarget>
  Some text
</p>
```

Here a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vvv3k4).

Comment: Why do that this way? Why not just put the HTML in the template, and use ngFor?

Comment: Can add that as well - he said in a comment that this is not working for him. Could have been a specific requirement or something that prevents him from using that.

Comment: I understand. But no. It's just that he/she doesn't understand the principles of Angular. A basic stackblitz example using  ngFor finally made him/her realize that it worked fine, of course. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57345596/how-to-create-button-dynamically-with-click-event-in-angular-2/57346148?noredirect=1#comment101179790_57345596

Comment: @pascalpuets,This way is also working.Thanks alot for your help.
Can you please check this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57239513/ng-template-with-ngfor-issue-in-angular-8

Comment: @JBNizet Seems I have missed that comment. Of course `*ngFor` is the most preferrable way to solve this. And one of the most basic things an angular developer should know.

Comment: @SupunAravinda Isn't that question already resolved? Not sure what you want me to add on there?

Comment: @pascalpuetz, One issue having when using this, Assume I have to dynamically add a row with multiple columns,those columns contains buttons,labels likewise,so if I use this way,any method to do this easily?

Comment: @pascalpuetz,I resolved this using *ngFor, I asked you that another question

Comment: @SupunAravinda Again, `*ngFor` is the preferable way. Add an array to your component.ts and iterate over it with `*ngFor`. If you want to use the renderer (which I only suggest if `*ngFor` is not capable of solving your issue) then you have to create and nest the elements using the method I showed you in this example (e.g. buttonText which is nested in button, you have to do that with ALL elements).

Comment: @pascalpuetz,hmm yeah. Thanks alo for your help and guidance. If You have a time,can you please check this one?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57239513/ng-template-with-ngfor-issue-in-angular-8