# Why doesn't the (click) fire when pressing button?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I've been trying to create html elements using this loop, but for some reason the button doesn't seem to fire at all.
Any ideas how this might be fixed?

```
let newListItem: any = '';
this.listArray.forEach((element, index) => {
   newListItem += `<ion-item>${element}</ion-item><ion-button (click)="console.log(${index})" fill="outline" slot="end"  color="danger")>remove</ion-button>`;
});
    itemList.innerHTML = newListItem;
```

Comment: The click event wont fire because your buttons are created dynamically. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57345596/how-to-create-button-dynamically-with-click-event-in-angular-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular event emitters and inputs/outputs must be converted from your HTML component declarations to valid HTML. This is not done in runtime, rather, it is done during the Angular build process (`ng build`).

Therefore, what you're trying to achieve with this code is plan impossible.

What you should do instead, is traverse the listArray in the HTML page using `ngFor`. Declare `listArray` as a public member of your class, then access it from the template. You need some HTML tag to wrap around the content, I will use `ion-item`:

```html
<ion-item *ngFor="let element of listArray; let i = index">
    <ion-item>{{element}}</ion-item>
    <ion-button (click)="console.log({{index}})" fill="outline" slot="end"  color="danger">remove</ion-button>
</ion-item>
```

PS: To remove the item from the list, which I think is your following intent in that "remove button", you would call `splice`:

```
<ion-button (click)="this.listArray.splice({{index}}, 1)" fill="outline" slot="end"  color="danger">remove</ion-button>
```

PS2: If there are HTML tags inside your `element` object, they will not be processed by this code, you should use `[innerHTML]` in that case (although it is strongly discouraged since it can bring performance and security problems)